# Force navigator.pop() to use a specific sceneConfig

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, react-native

While working with React Native Navigator, I have stumbled across the problem that it only supports the following sceneConfigs, by default:

```
Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight (default)
Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight
Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromLeft
Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom
Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottomAndroid
Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid
Navigator.SceneConfigs.HorizontalSwipeJump
Navigator.SceneConfigs.HorizontalSwipeJumpFromRight
Navigator.SceneConfigs.VerticalUpSwipeJump
Navigator.SceneConfigs.VerticalDownSwipeJump
```

Considering I needed a scene config with no transition at all, I've created the following custom sceneConfig, based on FadeAndroid transition:

```
const noTransition = {
  ...Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid,
  gestures: {},
  defaultTransitionVelocity: 1000,
  animationInterpolators: {
    into: buildStyleInterpolator(invisible),
    out: buildStyleInterpolator(invisible)
  }};
```

By doing that, whenever I want to push something into the Navigator, I call noTransition scene config:

```
gotoProfile: function () {
  _navigator.push({
    id: 'profile',
    sceneConfig: noTransition
  });
},
```

Also my "back" function when the user clicks a Back Arrow within the app is as following:

```
back: function () {
  if (_navigator.getCurrentRoutes().length > 1) _navigator.pop();
},
```

**The problem is:** When I click a back arrow within the app, I want the Navigator.pop() to happen with a transition that resembles a backward motion. But instead, the Navigator.pop() method transitions back by reverting the last used transition (which in most cases, is 'noTransition'. How can I force it to use a certain scene config instead of mimicking the last one? Thanks in advance.